# How to hide one of the mat-step of Material stepper without removing it from the DOM?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

How to hide one of the "mat-step" from the mat-horizontal-stepper?
I have set this css property:

```
display:none
```

but it is not working on "mat-step".

I do not want to remove that element from the DOM, so `*ngIf` is useless here.

I saw somewhere they use "

```
::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container { 
   display: none !important; 
}
```

But that works for entire . I only want to hide one .

I also tried

```
<mat-step style="display: none;"></mat-step>
```

without success.

I have a scenario like below:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper>
    <mat-step></mat-step>
    <mat-step></mat-step> // I just want to hide this step
    <mat-step></mat-step>
    <mat-step></mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reach the specific mat-step, use `:nth-of-type()` selector to reach that step via css. No need for the `::ng-deep`. You can put this either in the component's css, either in styles.css:

```
.mat-step-header:nth-of-type(2){ //for example, to remove the second step
  display:none;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3xjxz1-dwkhb9?file=src/app/stepper-overview-example.css)